# Octave/Matlab Error

Tags: matlab, error-handling, neural-network, octave

I am trying to implement a neural network with 3 hidden neurons,

The code causing me trouble is:

```
  bias = [-1 -1 -1];

  % Output layer
  x3_1 = bias(1,4)*weights(4,1) + x2(1)*weights(4,2) + x2(2)*weights(4,3) + x2(3)*weights(4,4);
  out(j) = sigmoid(x3_1);
```

I am getting the error:

*A(I,J): column index out of bounds; value 4 out of bound 3
error: called from '/home/8.m' in file /home/8.m near line 45, column 12*

Comment: The error is clearly stated. You are attempting to access column 4 when you only have 3 columns.

Comment: @excaza I have weights = ones(4,4); how can it be ?

Comment: @ferrer: just enable debugging: debug_on_error(1), then rerun script and wait until it stops, then evaluate your vars

Comment: @Andy thx. what is the command exactly?

Comment: "debug_on_error (1)" as I already wrote....

Comment: @Andy: in MATLAB, the command is `dbstop if error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `bias(1,4)` when bias is initialized to [-1 -1 -1].  It looks like you are missing a step where you update your bias values during each iteration, so they are always going to be [-1 -1 -1].

Comment: No bias is not updated actually, its weight is updated.